# SQL2008R2 Server access to XML templates in IIS7

Tags: iis-7, sql-server-2008-r2, xml

I'm in a jam. working on a migration project from SQL 2000 to SQL2008 R2 on a windows 2008 R2 box with IIS7 now installed.

The old server had 3 simple virtual directories with XML templates installed on them. The 'IIS Virtual Directory Management for SQL Server' was installed to control SQL account access to each of the folders so the code in the database could access the templates.

I have recreated the virtual directories on the new server, but SQL server IIS snap is now discontinued, can anyone shed anylight how I would configure this to work in IIS7 with SQL2008 R2?

Any Help much appreciated !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm amazed it works but I think I've solved this.

I installed iis on my back office SQL 2008 reporting server (I know its not recommended, but couldn't complete the migration without it). I then configured virutal directories in the exact same folder structure and files and the legacy 2000 server.

The client has tested with the amended URL and they are receiving their XML reports...

Answer (score 0):

Beginning with SQL 2005, SQLXML access by way of IIS virtual directories was discontinued.  For now, you can [**set up an HTTP endpoint**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181591.aspx) in SQL, but as of 2008 native XML native web services are deprecated and will be removed from a later version of SQL Server.

Microsoft recommends discontinuing use and converting things over to WCF or ASP.NET.  Have a look at [**this MSDN article**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280436.aspx).

When upgrading SQL Server, especially with as big of a jump as it is from SQL 2000 to SQL 2008 R2, you will want to run the [**upgrade advisor**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144256.aspx) when planning your upgrade.  That will help you catch situations like this.

Comment: yeah the problem i had was upgrade advisor would not install on the Old machine, sayig that it needed a newer service pack. On the new server it cannot detect the older machine using the same windows admin login, I have checked the remote registry service is enabled, but no joy. We are not performing a full upgrade, just recreate replication to a new big reporting server, but nobody mentioned that there were .xml templates hanging off the back.  Can I setup HTTP endpoints without having to rewrite any code ?